# Target all instances of Id in JS script to add class

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using the following code -

```
<script>var element = document.getElementById("more");
element.classList.add("wide");</script>
```

It is used in a php if statement. If a post in wordpress has a particular custom field completed it applies the class .wide to the post button which has an id of #more.

The problem is that if there are more than one instance of the id #more on the page (as there is in my excerpt pages) it only targets the first instance of #more and not the remaining post buttons on the page.

Is there a way to alter the above code so it targets ALL ids of "more" or any other way I can label the buttons I want targeted and change the code to target them all?

Comment: First off, you should never have more than one instance of the same `id`...

Comment: Completely agree. I used code from the internet to create my excerpts. I'm not targeting the id for anything else so will be taking it out but need to get this sorted first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should only ever be a single instance of a particular ID on a page, hence why the getElementById only returns a single value. If you want to use multiple then you should use a class and use that to target the elements you want to manipulate.

I would then suggest using jQuery or some other tool to simplify selecting the correct elements

eg:

```
<a class="more"></a>

<script>
    // Select .more elements and add the class wide.
    $('.more').addClass('wide');
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried using your code instead and adding the class more to the button but it's not working?

Comment: The code example uses jQuery, you will need to include that on the page prior to the script tag above, easiest way is to use their CDN and add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>` to your page. For more help visit [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com)

Comment: Because this is in the loop it is affecting all the elements on the page, not just the ones affected by the php if statement. Any ideas how I can get it to only affect that targeted ones?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're aware that multiple elements with the same ID is invalid HTML. However, since browsers are tolerant of that, you can use *querySelectorAll*, which works in IE8 and higher in standards mode and pretty much every other browser too:

```
var moreList = document.querySelectorAll('[id=more]');
```

Alternatively you can use *getElementsByTagName('*')* and loop over the returned members to collect those whose id is *more*.

You can then loop over the elements and add the class *wide*:

```
for (var i=0, iLen=moreList.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  addClass(moreList[i], 'wide');
}
```

with the following helpers (written many years ago and kept in a library):

```
function trim(s) {
  return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
}

function hasClass(el, className) {
  var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + className + '(\\s|$)');
  return re.test(el.className);
}

function addClass(el, className) {
  if (!hasClass(el, className)) {
    el.className = trim(el.className + ' ' + className);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried <script>var moreList = document.querySelectorAll('[id=more]');
element.classList.add("wide");</script> but it's not working? what have i done wrong?

Comment: You need to loop over the returned list as indicated in the answer.